# How to display 3 level of data into one single tableview in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, expandablelistview

My json data is an array of object in which inner array of objects data are there till 3 levels. I took first level json data in sections and 2nd level data in cell. now how can I display the third level of  data in single tableview ??

you can see the screen shot here

[image]

Till now only two levels done here. I need to display the 3rd label like this along with 2nd level..

[image]

my json data..

```
[
{
"id": "244",
"name": "PIZZAS",
"image": "",
"coupon": "1",
"icon": "",
"order": "1",
"aname": "",
"options": "2",
"subcategory": [
  {
    "id": "515",
    "name": "MARGARITA",
    "description": "Cheese and Tomato",
    "image": "",
    "icon": "",
    "coupon": "1",
    "order": "1",
    "aname": "",
    "options": "2",
    "item": [
      {
        "id": "1749",
        "name": "9 Inch Thin & Crispy Margarita",
        "description": "",
        "price": "3.40",
        "coupon": "1",
        "image": "",
        "options": "2",
        "order": "1",
        "addon": "495",
        "aname": "",
        "icon": ""
      },
```

Comment: You could create a `UITableViewCell` subclass and programatically add views to it (one view per style of Margarita pizza), laying them out vertically, using Autolayout. Provided that your table view is set for dynamic heights, your list of views will expand the cell vertically achieving the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `UITableViewDelegate`s method `tableView(_:indentationLevelForRowAt:)` to indent your 3rd level. Just implement that method in your delegate and return e.g. `20` for the rows that represent your 3rd level, `0` for all other rows.

**UPDATE**: Now I think to understand your problem. You will have to flatten your hierarchy because table views only support 2 levels natively. The 1st level can be implemented by means of tableview sections (as you already do). The 2nd and 3rd levels then can be implemented as rows, so you have to collapse these levels into one:

```
Pizzas                  Pizzas 
  Margaritha              Margaritha
    9InchThin             9InchThin
    12InchThin   -->      12InchThin
  BBQBasic                BBQBasic
    9InchThin             9InchThin
    12InchThin            12InchThin
```

In terms of Swift implementation, I'd suggest to use an Enum for representing the flattened rows:

```
enum ListItem {
  case TitleItem(TitleData)   // represents 2nd-level items
  case DetailItem(DetailData) // represents 3rd-level items
}
```

(`TitleData` is your model object containig e.g. "Margharita"/"Cheese and Tomato", `DetailData` is the model containing e.g. "9 Inch Thin & Crispy Margharita"/"£3,40".)

In `viewDidLoad:` create an array of `ListItem` for every section in your table: add a `TitleItem` for every title, followed by `DetailItem`s for all nested details. From your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` return the number of list items in that section. And finally in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` return a cell depending on the type of the list item:

```
let listItem = listItemForIndexPath(indexPath)
switch listItem {
case .TitleItem(let titleData): return titleCellWithData(titleData)
case .DetailData(let detailData): return detailCellWithData(detailData)
}
```

... where `titleCellWithData` and `detailCellWithData` of course should dequeue reusable cells from the table view.

Comment: it only add some space from front in each row that i defined as return

Comment: Yes that's what it is supposed to do.. sorry if that doesn't work for you, I probably did not fully understand your requirements.

Comment: please see the above screen shots. i need to add the third data like 9 inch , 12 inch..... .where should i take these . bcoz I  already took  the section and numberof rows in section.

Comment: I upated my answer accordingly. Maybe this works for you.

Comment: Is it possible that for cell, create  custom cell and add labels for 2nd level item and another tableview for the 3rd level items . I have used this scenario. but cant able to get the 3rd level data

Comment: this is the exact thing that you sent i need to do. But i am not able to do it. can you send the detailed solution please

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't give you the complete solution, that's up to you. But I advise you to check out some good tutorials on table views, custom cells and auto layout, because I think you lack some knowledge in these areas. For example, go through this tutorial by Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson7.html. Once you grasp these concepts, you will find it easy to apply the ideas I have written about.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117816/discussion-between-pradip-kumar-and-dr-barto).

Comment: hello @PradipKumar I am also having same problem if possible help me don't know how to implement tree view structure with three level and the url is http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cwqUAMjKGa?indent=2 and I also need to display like as shown in image link here https://i.stack.imgur.com/26Lj8.png

Comment: how do you expand third level I had also done using sections one level and cells for another level and now need to expand the another level ? @PradipKumar