# How to pass data through table views

Tags: swift, uitableview

my data structure sample..

```
  Sports  
      Bat-and-ball
           Baseball
           Softball
           Cricket
      Hockey
           Field Hockey
           Ice Hockey
           Roller Hockey
  Engineering  
      Computer Science
           Software Engineer
           Electrical Engineer
```

Here I have three level data as you can see . but by default in tableview it provides only upto 2 level. how can i display  the third level data.
I am only able to show the 1st level data in sections and second level data in rows using customcell. now where to display the third level data. so that i can iterate based on  number of rows..

my screen should be like that..

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to do it.

I will list a couple of them later.
But first you might think about whether it is a good user experience to show 3 levels of data in one table view. It might be difficult for the user to navigate through it.

So these are some options.

1. Show the top level data (let's call it a category) in a selector(dropdown) and then in a table view just have two levels (sections and rows) for the selected category.
   Here is an example of such dropdown view:
   https://github.com/PhamBaTho/BTNavigationDropdownMenu
2. If you really need to show a list with 3 levels of data you can have a table view, which will show the top level data as a section and second level as a row. For each row the corresponding cell will contain inside a table view (or might be just a stack view) showing just the rows for the 3rd level.

Comment: but my requirement is only this one .  I took 2 cell prototype. one for  displaying section data as 1st level.  on that i put the button to expand it. and then in 2nd prototype cell i am now displaying the 2nd level data . but  after expanding the 2nd and 3rd level should come at one time besed on its own iteration

Comment: Can you post screenshots or mocks then how it should look? What you are describing here is different from what you have asked in your question.

Comment: only i have changed the json data nothing else.. please see this screen there..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38460986

Comment: You can then go with the first approach that I've suggested. Put the top level data in a separate control (dropdown view). Then use this control as a tableHeaderView. Then use the 2nd level data for sections and 3rd level data for rows. 
So you just need to split your data into two parts:
1. Array of rows for dropdown (1st level)
2. Array of sections (2nd level) with rows (3rd level) for the table view

Comment: is it possible that i displayed 1st data in  sections. and then in row again take a tableview in which i could able to display the 2nd level in section of other tableview and 3rd data in its rows.

Comment: bcoz if i took the 1st level data in separate control. its not only a single row in 1st level. its an array of objects. so after every 3rd level ends  again i have to display the first level data.

Comment: i think your 2nd l option will help me in this. if u have some more details for using 2nd option it will be helpful for me

Comment: I see. Yes, then the second approach works better for you. 
So you use 1st level for sections.
Then for each row you have a custom cell, e.g. `MyCustomCell`.
Inside this custom cell class you add a table view.
Then in this table view you use sections for 2nd level of data and rows for 3rd level.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117893/discussion-between-pradip-kumar-and-fiks).

Answer (score 0):

you can add table in custom cell and 2nd and third level data can display on that inner table.

Comment: ok then how the 2nd and 3rd level will relate to the 1st level. i mean the countings. if u have any sample please send

Comment: in custom cell you just pass array to another cell array in cell for row method dictionaryVitals.count>0
                {
                cell.datatitleArray = dictionarydata[0] as! NSArray
                cell.dateArray = dictionarydata[1] as! NSArray
                }

Answer (score 0):

> This code ran beautifully on my device.

**Storyboard**
[image]

**TableViewController1**

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController1: UITableViewController {

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return group1.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = group1[indexPath.row].title

    return cell
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "segue1" {

        let indexPaths = self.tableView!.indexPathsForSelectedRows!
        let indexPath = indexPaths[0] as NSIndexPath

        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! TableViewController2
        vc.currentGroup = group1[indexPath.row].title

    }
}
}
```

**TableViewController2**

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController2: UITableViewController {

var currentGroup: String?
var filteredData = [Data]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for data in group2 {

        if data.group == currentGroup {
            filteredData.append(data)
        }

    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return filteredData.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = filteredData[indexPath.row].title

    return cell
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "segue2" {

        let indexPaths = self.tableView!.indexPathsForSelectedRows!
        let indexPath = indexPaths[0] as NSIndexPath

        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! TableViewController3
        vc.currentGroup = group2[indexPath.row].title

    }
}
}
```

**TableViewController3**

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController3: UITableViewController {

var currentGroup: String?
var filteredData = [Data]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for data in group3 {

        if data.group == currentGroup {
            filteredData.append(data)
        }

    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return filteredData.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = filteredData[indexPath.row].title

    return cell
}

}
```

**Data Class**

```
import Foundation

class Data {

var title: String
var group: String?

init (title: String, group: String?) {
    self.title = title
    self.group = group
}
}

let group1 = [Data(title: "Sport", group: nil), Data(title: "Engineering", group: nil)]
let group2 = [Data(title: "Hockey", group: "Sport"), Data(title: "CS", group: "Engineering")]
let group3 = [Data(title: "Ice Hockey", group: "Hockey"), Data(title: "Software Engineer", group: "CS")]
```

*P.S. I hate to make things complicated.*

*Happy hacking!*

Comment: but i took inner tableview inside custom cell. so there is no segue here. my requirement is to take all data in one tableview. not three different tableview connected thru segue.